# Please create a "hermeneutics" tag

Tags: discussion, tags

I realize that having a "hermeneutics" tag may seem overly generic to some... they might think "well surely we don't want an *exegesis* tag linked to every exegesis question, so why would we want a *hermeneutics* tag?" Others may object on the grounds that we already have a "hermeneutical approaches" tag. However, **I think we need one -- at least for now, and here is why:**

- We don't have many hermeneutics questions, so the first objection is invalid.
- There are many potential hermeneutics questions that are not questions about *hermeneutical approaches*, so the second objection is invalid.
- For people like me who are far more interested in "hermeneutics" than "exegesis", there is no way to track hermeneutics questions as a "favorite" tag if it doesn't exist.

I recently posted [a question](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/7679/529) about how to identify literary genre. The only tag I could find that might be relevant was "litarary-genre" (which is an appropriate tag), but my question isn't about hermeneutical approaches, so I couldn't use that tag [...before I continue that sentence let me prove my claim:

- A person's hermeneutical approaches does not indicate their criteria for determining genre

  - People using different hermeneutical approaches may well use the same criteria for determining genre -- in fact, it is conceivable that people from every hermeneutical approach could share the same criteria for genre identification
  - Within a single hermeneutical approach (e.g. Historical-Grammatical) there may well be *many* different opinions about how to properly determine genre
- I'm not really asking about the peculiarities of Historical-Critical, Sensus Plenior, Pardes, or the slew of other hermeneutical systems.

Thus, my question is not a question about hermeneutical approaches. Back to my sentence...] nor is it specific to NT or OT, nor to a particular book of the Bible, etc. So **there is no tag out there for the miscellaneous hermeneutics questions that are not asking about hermeneutical approaches.**

There may come a day when the "hermeneutics" tag gets unwieldy and needs to be **replaced** with new tags which can cover all of the bases in smaller segments, but for now, can we get the "hermeneutics" tag back?

Comment: Does it pass the [two tests here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/)? namely: 1. If the tag can’t work as the only tag on a question, it’s probably a meta-tag, 2. If the tag commonly means different things to different people, it’s probably a meta-tag.

Comment: For the record my -1 is in the meta tradition of disagreement on a conclusion rather than post quality, otherwise it would be +1 in a heartbeat for constructive contribution to the site.

Comment: @Caleb gotcha. thanks for clarifying

Comment: Just posted [a new meta question](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/3274) related to this one you posted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I appreciate the thought you've put into taxonomy and even if we disagree on this case I believe it is helping to improve the site. My main concern is that this tag would quickly turn into a meta tag. Of course there would be a way to use it that wasn't too meta-y, but we would constantly be ripping it out of places in didn't belong.

As for the one example question you cite I think it's somewhat of an edge case. We have very few like it and I think for now it is best lumped in with [hermeneutical-approaches](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hermeneutical-approaches). That being said I would love to see more questions like it and perhaps as we get more another pattern will emerge that distinguishes them.

In the mean time I think you'll just have to follow more than one tag to pick up everything you're interested in. The SE engine makes this fairly easy to build a whole collection of tags to focus in on.